# how to access to lost process?

Tags: linux, process

Let's assume I run putty on windows and connect to Debian Jessie remotely.
I run Midnight commander, and run long term task. Than got power loss on Windows, so putty connection is lost.

Of course I should use screen, but i forgot.

After reconnection I can see mc in `ps ax`.

```
 1864 pts/3    S+     0:10 mc
```

Is there a way to reconnect to this process? (And is it running?)

Comment: In case this does get migrated to [unix.se] it will also be a duplicate on that site: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4034/68601

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope there isn't, that terminal from where you have launched Midnight commander was the parent process. Once the parent dies the child will die. You should have used screen or disowned the process some how, but now its gone.